# Why is a decimal.Decimal object not considered rational?

Tags: python, decimal, rational-number

A python `Decimal` stores a base 10 number, which can be thought of as a ratio with a power of 10 on the bottom.

So why does this fail?

```
from decimal import Decimal
from numbers import Rational

assert issubclass(Decimal, Rational)
```

Comment: `assert` fails because `Decimal` is not a subclass of `Rational`. Why is it not a subclass of `Rational` is a different question.

Comment: From a cursory glance at the decimal docs I see that this module does some kind of roundoff which fractions as far as I know don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same reason `float` isn't `Rational`: while all non-infinite, non-NaN values of `float` or `Decimal` are rational, the types are intended to model real-number arithmetic. For example, they support square roots:

```
2.0**0.5
Decimal(2).sqrt()
```

which a class intended to model rational numbers or a subset of the rationals would not.

(Yes, okay, you can do `2**0.5`, but that coerces the int to a float.)

Comment: Right, my mistake is confusing "stores a rational number" and "supports only rational operations"